# Plot ahead of time Pivot Points Intraday

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to plot ahead of time pivot points.
If today is Friday, it should plot on Monday and **keep its location till the Market opens.**

Similarly,
If today is Weekday, should plot on Next Day and **keep its location till the Market opens.**

There are no errors in the code, what is the issue and solution?

**I want a solution for all markets, not just time specific for a particular market.**

```
//@version=5
indicator("Plot Ahead of Time", overlay=true)





//TIME
//*******************************************************************
var int time_tomorrow_start_line    = na
var int time_tomorrow_end_line      = na
time_check_2                        = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow) , hour(00), minute(00), second(00))
Time_one_day                        = 86400000

if time_check_2 ==  dayofweek.friday // TODAY IS FRIDAY PLOT ON MONDAY                  friday      saturday        sunday          monday                                
    time_tomorrow_start_line    := timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow + Time_one_day + Time_one_day + Time_one_day ) , hour(00), minute(00))
    time_tomorrow_end_line      :=  time_tomorrow_start_line    + Time_one_day  



//LOCATION
//*******************************************************************
// Get series
get_security(e, timeFrame) =>    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeFrame, e, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

//Get High, Low and Close
H_d_Tomorrow = get_security(high  , 'D')
L_d_Tomorrow = get_security(low   , 'D')
C_d_Tomorrow = get_security(close , 'D')


//cenral pivot range
DayPivot_Tomorrow   = ((H_d_Tomorrow + L_d_Tomorrow + C_d_Tomorrow) / 3) 




//PLOT
//*******************************************************************
var line DayPivot_Tomorrow_line = na 
DayPivot_Tomorrow_line := line.new(x1 = time_tomorrow_start_line , y1 = DayPivot_Tomorrow ,   x2 = time_tomorrow_end_line , y2 = DayPivot_Tomorrow ,            xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=line.style_solid, width  = 1, color  = color.new(#E040FB,0) )//
line.delete(DayPivot_Tomorrow_line[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the (time_check_2)  from your script.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).